# v-list in v-list not working with vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to implement list in list using vuetify. But I didnt manage to make it work. Below is the code and sample data. Please help me make it work. I am using vuetify 2.3.10. If I comment out the part for the second list then the first list works

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <v-toolbar id="filter">
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 md1>
              <v-menu attach="#filter-users" offset-y>
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                  <div class="dropdown" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">User</div>
                </template>
                <v-list id="filter-users">
                  <v-list-item
                    v-for="search_user in search_users"
                    @click="filterUser({user: search_user})">
                    <v-list-item-title>{{ search_user.name }}</v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item>
                  <v-list v-if="search_user.sub_users.length">
                    <v-list-item v-for="(search_sub_users, index) in search_user.sub_users"
                                 :key="`sub_user_${index}`"
                                 @click="filterUsers({user: search_sub_user})">
                      <v-list-item-title>{{ search_sub_user.name }}</v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item>
                  </v-list>
                </v-list>
              </v-menu>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-toolbar>
      </div>
    </template>
```

search_users demo data

```
search_users:[{
  name: 'James',
  sub_users: [
    {
    name: 'Willy'
    },
    {
    name: 'Jack'
    },
  }]
 },
 name: 'Rock',
 sub_users: [
   {
    name: 'Randy'
    },
    {
    name: 'Amy'
    },
  }]
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of things going on in your code so let me enumerate them for you:

1. On your second sub-list, it can't find the `search_user` variable since that variable is only accessible inside the `<v-list-item/>`, which is outside of the `<v-list/>`.

   What you can do is to create a `<template/>` that will wrap both `<v-list-item/>` and `<v-list/>` then put the `v-for` there. Something like this:

   ```html
   <v-list ...>

     <template v-for="(search_user, index) in search_users">
       <v-list-item :key="`user_${index}`">...</v-list-item>  <!-- User List -->
       <v-list :key="`sub_user_${index}`">...</v-list>        <!-- Sub User List -->
     </template>

   </v-list>
   ```

   Also, don't forget the `v-bind:key`, or simply `:key`, to the `v-for`'s child elements.
2. You attempt to attach the `<v-menu/>` to its default slot. The `attach` prop of `<v-menu/>` should be somewhere outside the `<v-menu/>` or inside the its activator slot. However, it should attach directly to the element in your activator slot by default so you can just omit the `attach` prop.

   ```html
   <v-menu offset-y> <!-- remove the `attach` prop -->
     <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
       <div class="dropdown" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">User</div>
     </template>
     <v-list>...</v-list>
   </v-menu>
   ```
3. On your second sub-list, you mistakenly typed `search_sub_user` instead of `search_sub_users`:

   ```js
   v-for="(search_sub_users, index) in search_user.sub_users"` // wrong
   v-for="(search_sub_user, index) in search_user.sub_users"`  // right
   ```

[image]

Here is a refactored version of your code at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-leftpad-cb201?file=/src/components/Playground.vue).